# Void variable company-active-map

Tags: debugging, company

I am getting a weird void variable error despite using what I thought would be a very appropriate `with-eval-after-load`.

Here is my company config.

```
(use-package company
  :commands (company-complete-common
             company-complete
             company-complete-common-or-cycle
             company-manual-begin
             company-grab-line)
  :hook (after-init . global-company-mode)
  ;; :bind ("TAB" . company-indent-or-complete-common)
  ;; :bind ("C-SPC" . company-indent-or-complete-common)
  :init
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2
        company-tooltip-limit 14
        company-tooltip-align-annotation t
        company-require-match 'never


        ;; These auto-complete the current selection when
        ;; `company-auto-commit-chars' is typed. This is too magical. We
        ;; already have the much more explicit RET and TAB.
        company-auto-commit nil
        ;; Only search the current buffer for `company-dabbrev' (a backen
d that
        ;; suggests text your open buffers). This prevents Company from c
ausing
        ;; lag once you have a lot of buffers open.
        company-dabbrev-other-buffers nil
        ;; Make `company-dabbrev' fully case-sensitive, to improve UX wit
h
        ;; domain-specific words with particular casing.
        company-dabbrev-ignore-case t
        company-dabbrev-downcase nil

        ;; only give company when asked for
        company-idle-delay nil)
  :config

  ;; Buffer-local backends will be computed when loading a major mode, so
  ;; only specify a global default here. `'
  (setq company-backends '(company-capf company-files))
)

(with-eval-after-load 'company
    ;; make ESC abort from here: https://github.com/noctuid/general.el/is
sues/105
  (evil-make-intercept-map company-active-map 'insert)
  (general-def company-active-map [escape] 'company-abort))
```

Still, I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable company-active-map)
  (evil-make-intercept-map company-active-map 'insert)
  (closure (t) nil (evil-make-intercept-map company-active-map 'insert) (general-define-key :keymaps 'company-active-map [escape] 'company-abort))()
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Maybe you need to quote that variable in the call to `evil-make-intercept-map`?

Comment: cannot reproduce on my side.